# Calculating the point where two circles touch based on circle1's velocity

Tags: javascript, math, vector, simulation, physics

We have two circles, Circle1 & Circle2, Circle2 is static and Circle1 is moving.

Circle1 = C1, Circle2 = C2.

C1 has a velocity and direction which will cause it to touch C2 at one point.

v is a vector describing C1's velocity.
d is the distance from the center point of C1 to the center point of C2.

We also know the radius of both circles.

Frame 1:

[image]

C1 has not yet collided with C2, but as we can see it will in the next frame do so.

Frame 2:

[image]

C1 is now intersecting with C2.

Frame 2 (after calculation):

[image]

C1 has now been positioned at the point where it first touched C2.

So the question is, how can we calculate (preferably in js) the point along v where C1 should stop?

Current code:

```js
//    x^2 + B * x + C = 0
//    x= v'
//    B = 2 * (d.x * v.x + d.y*v.y)/Math.sqrt(v.x*v.x + v.y*v.y)
//    C = (d.length()^2 - rs^2)

// get distance from ri to ri2 as a vector.
var d = new Vector(ri2.x - ri.x, ri2.y - ri.y);
// get sum of radiuses.
var rs = ri.r + ri2.r;

var A = 1;
var B = 2 * (d.x * v.x + d.y*v.y)/Math.sqrt(v.x*v.x + v.y*v.y);
var C = (d.length()^2 - rs^2);

var x1 = (-B + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(B, 2) - 4 * A * C)) / 2 * A;
var x1 = (-B - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(B, 2) - 4 * A * C)) / 2 * A;

// and then we get the lowest positive of x1 & x2.
```

Comment: repost in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Center-center distance in the touch moment is

```
R12 = R1 + R2
```

So using cosine theorem:

R12<sup>2</sup> = v'<sup>2</sup> + d<sup>2</sup> - 2*d*v'*Cos(dv)

Solve this quadratic equation against v' and get smaller positive solution value (if 2 cases exist).

You can find Cos(dv) through scalar product of vectors **d** and **v**

Cos(dv) = **d** * **v** / (|**d**||**v**|)

So final quadratic equation is

v'<sup>2</sup> - v' * 2 * (**d** * **v**) / |**v**| + (d<sup>2</sup> - R12<sup>2</sup>) = 0

for standart form

```
x^2 + B * x + C = 0    
x= v'
B =  -2 * (d.x * v.x + d.y*v.y)/Sqrt(v.x*v.x + v.y*v.y)
C = (d^2 - R12^2)
```

Check for simple case: circle radius 2 centered at (0,0), moving right (v = (10,0)); static circle radius 3 centered (6,3). Result should be v'=2

```
B = -2*(6*10+3*0)/10= -12
C=45-(2+3)^2=20
Determinant = B*B - 4*C = 144-80 = 64
v'= (12 +- 8)/2
smaller value v'=2
```

[image]

Comment: This looks promising. Could you try to give me a pointer on how to do this programmatically?

Comment: What is problem - quadratic equation solving, scalar product, something else?

Comment: Calculating v' and the quadratic equation solving. As for the scalar product using the built in Math.cos(dv); in js should suffice.

Comment: Usual form of quadratic equation is `x^2 + B * x + C = 0`, and here unknown x =v',     B = 2 * (d * v) / |v| and C =  (d^2 - R12^2)

Comment: Ok. Just to clarify what exactly does v' mean?

Comment: v' is distance from former C1 center to new C1 center (black part of v at the last picture)

Comment: This is my take on solving the equation against v', but there seems to be a problem.
v' = ((2 * Math.cos(d * v)) + Math.sqrt(-(Math.pow((2 * Math.cos(d * v)), 2))-4*(Math.pow(d, 2)-Math.pow(r12, 2))) / 2)

Comment: Read about scalar product of two `vectors`. It is d.x*v.x + d.y*v.y

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82459/discussion-between-node-and-mbo).

Answer (score 1):

You need to solve a few steps

1. Set up [equation of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#General_planar_motion) and impose criteria that circles touch

   ***| P<sub>1</sub> + v * t - P<sub>2</sub> | = R<sub>1</sub> + R<sub>1</sub>***

   where ***P<sub>1</sub>*** and ***P<sub>2</sub>*** are the initial positions of the circle 1 and 2, respectively, and ***t*** is time.
2. Square the equation and solve for the intersection time using the [quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation)
3. Use intersection time to solve for the intersection location of circle 1
4. Once you have where circle 1 is at the moment of intersection, and since circle 2 is static, solve [circle-circle intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(Euclidean_geometry)#Two_circles) problem

Answer (score 0):

for each x,y on your V line
calculate the distance between the centers of C1 and C2.
it the distance equals to r1+r2 then the circles touch eternally.

P2(x2,y2) is center of C2
P1(x1,y1) is calculated center for C1 moving on V

P1P2 distance is:

```
SQuare Root of: (x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2
```

once this equals r1+r2 you should stop

Distnace function for javascript is:

```
var d = Math.sqrt( (x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2) );
```

or if you wish:

```
var dist = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((x1-x2), 2) + Math.pow((y1-y2), 2) );
```